# Why there is a NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before click:

[image]

After click:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var output = document.getElementById("whole");
            if (!navigator.geolocation) {
                $("#whole").html("<p>Your brower is not supported</p>");
                return;
            }

            function success(position) {
                var lan = position.coords.latitude;
                var lon = position.coords.longitude;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lan + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=f06e25b1205b65171ad01524870cbb01",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#temp").text(Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15));
                    }
                });
            }

            function error() {
                output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

            var ce = parseInt($("#temp").text(), 10);
            var fa = Math.round(ce * 1.8 + 32);

            $("a").on("click", function () {
                if ($(this).text() == "℃") {
                    $(this).html("℉");
                    $("#temp").text(fa);
                } else {
                    $(this).html("℃");
                    $("#temp").text(ce);
                }
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <span id="temp"></span><a id="toggle" href="javascript:void(0)">℃</a>
```

I want to achieve this,when I click the Celcius character,the Celius degree will change into Fahrenheit degree.Because the code need the location, so running the snippet will throw an error.I don't know why there is a NaN.But didn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those variables are not global since the are declared in the scope of the `ready` function.

Use their names directly (*without the `window`*) as your `click` handler is also in the same scope.

```
document).ready(function () {
    var ce = parseInt($("#temp").text(), 10);
    var fa = Math.round(ce * 1.8 + 32);

    $("a").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "℃") {
            $(this).html("℉");
            $("#temp").text(fa);
        } else {
            $(this).html("℃");
            $("#temp").text(ce);
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Update**

The problem is that the `#temp` element has no value at the time you run the code, since it is filled from an AJAX call (*which is asynchronous and completes at a later time*)

You should put the parsing code inside the success callback of the AJAX.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var output = document.getElementById("whole");
            var ce, fa;
            if (!navigator.geolocation) {
                $("#whole").html("<p>Your brower is not supported</p>");
                return;
            }

            function success(position) {
                var lan = position.coords.latitude;
                var lon = position.coords.longitude;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lan + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=f06e25b1205b65171ad01524870cbb01",
                    success: function (data) {
                        ce = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15);
                        fa = Math.round(ce * 1.8 + 32);
                        $("#temp").text( ce );
                    }
                });
            }

            function error() {
                output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

            $("a").on("click", function () {
                if ($(this).text() == "℃") {
                    $(this).html("℉");
                    $("#temp").text(fa);
                } else {
                    $(this).html("℃");
                    $("#temp").text(ce);
                }
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="temp"></span><a id="toggle" href="javascript:void(0)">℃</a>
```

Comment: The code I post before is a snippet of my whole work.Your answer can solve the question before.But just can't solve my whole work's problem.I update the question.Can you have a look?

Comment: After the `#temp` element is filled from the Ajax call, clicking the `#temp` element , the two line: `var ce = parseInt($("#temp").text(), 10);` and `var fa = Math.round(ce * 1.8 + 32);` didn't excute?

Comment: In your original code, the `var ce=...` and `var fa = ..` had run once on page load, when the `#temp` element was empty. It did not run again on `click` since it was outside of that handler.

Comment: I cannot completely agree with you. In my original code,the Ajax call is executed before the `var ce = ...` and `var fa = ...`.It can't be empty?

Comment: I am new fresher of JS. I guess `var fa = ... ` and `var ce = ...` annoucement will be check first before the script is excuted? so thats make sense.

Comment: @gaby read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323 for a good explanation of what AJAX stands for and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. check this [**Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/rzr3j9c9/2/)

```
 <span id="temp">178</span><a id="toggle" href="javascript:void(0)">℃</a>
    window.ce;
    window.fa;
$(document).ready(function () {
         ce = parseInt($("#temp").text(), 10);
         fa = Math.round(ce * 1.8 + 32);
        $("a").on("click", function () {
            if ($(this).text() == "℃") {
                $(this).html("℉");
                $("#temp").text(window.fa);
            } else {
                $(this).html("℃");
                $("#temp").text(window.ce);
            }
        });
    });
```